# My VBA code to open Chrome and use the text from a cell is opening multiple tabs instead of just 1

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome

I have some text in cell B3 which I want to use to search Chrome. Sometimes the text has several words and for each word it is opening a separate tab. How do I work the code below to use the full text in a single tab?

Dim search As String

search = Range("b3").Value

Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url " & search)

Comment: Have you any parenthesis around search? like `"one two three"`

Comment: im afraid im not sure what you mean by parenthesis?

Comment: Like the example `"one two three"` or are you passing like `one two three`

Comment: you put me on the right path, a quick dummies guide to parenthesis has solved it. thanks

Comment: no worries.  They can quickly become confusing in themselves :o)